# How to play RTMP live stream on HTML5 player without Flash and NGINX

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, rtmp

How can I stream live RTMP video on HTML5 player on shared cpanel without Flash or NGINX?

Are there any open source javascript, jQuery, PHP library?

Comment: not that I know of. you'll need either nginx-rtmp or a similar transcoder to get the content to something html5 video can display - pretty easy setup eg https://gist.github.com/Manishfoodtechs/5feb532fb626ece6a92698a1e5b6a984

Answer (score 0):

Flash is disabled in H5, so it's not able to use Flash to play video stream.

Rather than Flash, you should use HTTP-FLV/HLS/WebRTC for H5. All theses protocols are natively supported by H5, so you should covert the RTMP stream.

SRS supports coverting RTMP to HTTP-FLV/HLS/WebRTC for H5 to play the video stream, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).

You could also use FFmpeg to covert RTMP to HLS, then deliver by any web server.