# How to create my own custom RMTP server from scratch and stream to multiple destinations

Tags: flutter, nginx, server, video-streaming, live-streaming

I am using [StreamYard](https://streamyard.com/) services to do a live stream to multiple destinations like Facebook and youtube. I want to create a mobile app using flutter that can receive that stream and use it (i mean to display the live stream). Streamyard uses only [RMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol) for a custom destination.

My question is: is there a way to create and host a custom RMTP online that can be shared between the StreamYard platform and my mobile app. I want it to work whenever I do live stream from the StreamYard it will be shared to Facebook, youtube, and my mobile app as well. I have done a lot of research but i find out the only way is to use windows or linux as a host, which i want it online.

Also, alternative solutions are welcome like using webRTC.

Comment: Why do you need to create your own RTMP server from scratch?  Some simple scripting with FFmpeg can accomplish what you need, if I'm understanding your need correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use StreamYard, I think you need to use the `INVITE` feature to start a `Video Chat` then convert to live streaming, it works like bellow:

```
UserA --WebRTC--->---+
                     +--->- StreamYeard -->-RTMP-->- YouTube/Twitch.tv
UserB --WebRTC---->--+
```

You need to buy a [non-free plan](https://streamyard.com/plan) to support `Custom RTMP destinations` to publish the RTMP to your media server like [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs) or Nginx, then you could broadcast to multiple destination, like this:

```
                    +->-- YouTube/Twitch.tv
                    |
StreamYeard ->-RTMP-+->- Custom RTMP destinations --+--RTMP-> YouTube/Twitch.tv
                         (SRS/Nginx media server)   |
                                                    +--HLS/FLV--> Flutter App
```

> Note: Once streaming to your RTMP server or video cloud platform, you could covert to HLS/HTTP-FLV for your FlutterAPP to play it. About player and protocol, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565). It depends on which part you want to build by yourself, and it's possible to build by open-source projects.

> Note: Note that you could use StreamYeard to streaming to YouTube and Custom RTMP server, or use FFmpeg to pull stream from your custom server then publish to any other live streaming platform.

For this solution, the StreamYeard actually plays as `Video Chat` or video conference platform, like ZOOM. It will transcode each WebRTC stream and mix all the audio and videos to one RTMP stream.

So you could use WebRTC server to build your `StreamYeard`, then use FFmpeg to transcode and mix the streams, because it is off topic so let me stop here.