# Live streaming in Flutter web using RTMP link

Tags: flutter-web, rtmp, live-streaming

I am trying to implement live streaming using an rtmp link in flutter web, and could not find players which supports web. Can anyone advice which player to use and how to implement the same?

I have tried chewie, agora , video text rtmp publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use H5 player to play live streaming by RTMP? It doesn't work now. Because RTMP player depends on Adobe Flash, which is completely disalbed right now(at 2021.12).

However, HTTP-FLV is a replace for RTMP, for both H5 and mobile, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70429640/17679565).

Remember that HLS and WebRTC is also a possible solution, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).