# Live Video Streaming on Flutter WEB

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, live-streaming

I am trying to implement Live Streaming using third party server and that server only provide **RTMP link and stream key** .
Can anyone suggest any plug-in which will enable me to do live streaming of a flutter web app. The RTMP link needs to be played in the web. Please suggest plugin which can help in doing so. I have the IP address and stream key with me.

Android & IOS: we are using plug-in for android & ios

Comment: Have you tried this plug in? https://pub.dev/packages/video_js or this one https://pub.dev/packages/ext_video_player

Comment: One more option https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_live

Comment: Hey bro, maybe this link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718276/live-streaming-in-flutter-web-using-rtmp-link