# video.js cannot use rtmp from Https website

Tags: video.js, rtmp

I am using video.js to play a audio rtmp

works fine in localhost:8000 (since http)

but on website which is https it fails : with a message that it can only run on http server Or i need to secure my rtmp server(which i have no control)

Comment: Your demo does an HTTPS check in the script, remove that and try again or simply apply SSL self-signed and bypass till you're on a real domain-name/etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about HTTPS, it's because H5(`video.js`) is not able to play the RTMP stream.

Note that Flash is disabled in [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en) and other browsers right now(at 2022.01), see [Adobe: Adobe Flash Player EOL General Information Page](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html).

So, for H5 player like `video.js/flv.js/hls.js`, it's not able to play RTMP stream, neither HTTP nor HTTPS, you should user a media server to covert RTMP to `HLS/HTTP-FLV/WebRTC`, depends on your use scenario.

About live streaming players and protocols, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).