# Fetch video data from RTMP Streaming link to browser

Tags: reactjs, video.js, rtmp, multimedia

Is there a way to fetch an RTMP live video stream to a simple browser created on REACT?. I have tried various methods including the one with Video.js. But I get an error like "No compatible sources found for this media" and some other times the player is stuck in a kind of buffering situation with no data. I just need the data from the RTMP link to be like in a simple video player. Any Solutions? Thank You.

Comment: I also did the html video tags like :
`<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="70" width="300" controls autoplay preload="none"><source src="{rtmp link}" type="rtmp/mp4"/></video>`

Comment: Flash Is required to play RTMP in a browser, and browsers no longer support Flash.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that on many docs. However is it possible to convert this into an HLS output? Then I just need to code a browser that can play HLS right?

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to play RTMP on REACT H5 video player, you need a media server to covert to HTTP-FLV/HLS/WebRTC, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).

These protocols introduce different lagging, HTTP-FLV is most likely RTMP about 1~3s latency, while HLS is about 5~10s, and WebRTC is the most realtime about 0.6~1s.