# Which protocol to use for multi-stream application ? RTMP?

Tags: networking, websocket, server, streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to stream several iPad screen to a single python client (computer) on a local network but I don't know which protocol to use.
I can do it with 1 Ipad using *MonaServer*, an app that stream on RTMP and a little Python script to read the video.
But I am dealing with problems to use several Ipads because as I saw RTMP uses a single port on Windows, :1935 and I am not sure it's possible to multi-stream with RTMP.
I am not a pro with networking, so if you have any suggestions I'm open

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to following the wiki and usage of open source projects, to get some instincts about multiple clients live streaming.

For example, you could use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) to publish some streams to a media server, like [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs), play it by different protocols like RTMP/HTTP-FLV/HLS/WebRTC.

You could publish multiple streams, they are not mutually exclusive. And play by different players, depends on the protocol you chose, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).

Try it.