# RTSP- Broadcasting Streams?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, media, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm fifty tabs deep on google, and can't find any definitive answers to my question, or chances are i just don't understand if well enough to realise -

So i have access to an ip camera on the internet, and it outputs an RTSP feed - my question is:

Is there a limit to how many times a single RTSP feed can be consumed? i had been told that the feed is effectively 'broadcast' to all consumers - but in my mind that would require a lot of processing and duplication of frames.

ultimately this is all to say, will i require a media sever of some description to support many consumers?

Apologies for my limited understanding of this topic, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on your clients or players, say.

Generally, you need a media server to broadcast the RTSP stream to all players, which works like this:

```
IP Camera --RTSP--> FFmpeg --RTMP--> Media Server --RTMP/HLS/WebRTC--> Players
```

It obviously depends on your players, for example, if you would like multiple H5 browser like Chrome to play the stream, you should use HLS/WebRTC, and you should choose media server to covert RTMP to HLS/WebRTC, like [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs).

Note that you're not able to broadcast the RTSP stream to all players directly, especially for:

- There are lots of players, say, 10k players consuming the stream, you need a media server cluster, not only a media server.
- Rather than some player could play RTSP, such as VLC, some players might not play the RTSP stream, but HLS or WebRTC, like described there, please read more from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400665/17679565).
- If you want to deliver the RTSP stream over internet, YouTube, Twitch as such, you should use RTMP to push to theses platforms.

So it really depends on your use scenarios and latency etc, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).