# How to broadcast a live stream via FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

I'm very new to `ffmpeg`. Consider `http://example.com/live` is a remote stream source. I want to get the stream from that source and then broadcast it as **MPEG-TS**, **HLS** and **RTMP** to my users. I know ffmpeg can send data to a **rtmp/udp/tcp** server. But the whole process is ambiguous to me.

Long story short, how can I get the stream from remote source and then broadcast it as **MPEG-TS**, **HLS** and **RTMP**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a media server to covert protocols and serve players, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359019/17679565), to which push by ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i http://xxx -c copy -f flv rtmp://server/live/xxx
```

Note that RTMP does not work for H5 player, HTTP-FLV or WebRTC is a optional for low latency live streaming, or HLS/DASH for normal latency, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't upvote cause it needs at least 15 reputation.

Comment: Never mind, it's really OK :)